# Connection refused in opencart hosted in google cloud

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, opencart, bitnami

I have installed bitnami-opencart in google cloud everything worked fine but after implementation of SSL. my website down and it shows following error.

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 8
Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 11
Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 11
```

Comment: What do you mean with SSL implementation? Did you configure SSL on Apache or did you change anything else on the configuration? The error you're facing it's complaining about being unable to connect to the MySql database.

Comment: Seems like your MySQL Database is not getting connected, it doesn't have anything to do with SSL. maybe try restarting the MySQL service, it may have been dead/stuck.